# Automtically tickeing a PNR, usage of DesignatePrinter

Tags: sabre

At the moment I'm creating a ticketing robot. As part of the process, just like in Galileo, I need to "link" a ticket printer to my current connection/session before being able to send a ticketing request.

The documentation isn't however very clear on how to form my DesignatePrinter request.

At the moment I'm doing this the following way:

```
var messageHeader = new MessageHeader
{
    ConversationId = "TestSession",
    CPAId = licenseId,
    Action = "DesignatePrinterLLSRQ",
    Service = new Service { Value = "DesignatePrinterLLSRQ" },
    MessageData = new MessageData
    {
        MessageId = "xxx:xxxxxx",
        Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + "Z"
    },
    From = new From()
    {
        PartyId = new[]
        {
            new PartyId {Value = "WebServiceClient"}
        }
    },
    To = new To()
    {
        PartyId = new[]
        {
            new PartyId {Value = "WebServiceSupplier"}
        }
    }
};
```

Since the idea is to ticket I assign a DesignatePrinterRQPrintersTicket  to the request object, like this:

```
var request = new   
{
    Version = "2.25.0",
    TimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
    TimeStampSpecified = true,
    Printers = new DesignatePrinterRQPrinters
    {
        Ticket = new DesignatePrinterRQPrintersTicket { LNIATA = printers }
    }
};

DesignatePrinterRS resp = null;
Policy.Handle<SoapException>()
    .Or<WebException>()
    .WaitAndRetry(new[]
    {
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    })
    .Execute(() =>
    {
        using (
            DesignatePrinterService serviceObj = new DesignatePrinterService())
        {
            serviceObj.MessageHeaderValue = messageHeader;
            serviceObj.Security = new Security1 { BinarySecurityToken = token };
            resp = serviceObj.DesignatePrinterRQ(request);
        }
    });

if (resp != null && resp.ApplicationResults.status == CompletionCodes.Complete)
{
    //  Ticket printer linked
    resultValue = 1;
}
else
{
    //  Ticket printer not linked
    resultValue = 0;
}
```

Is this sufficient or do I need more?

I'm not able to test at the moment unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

can you post the generated output XML?

Normally, something like this would work, to designate a ticket printer using the DesignatePrinterLLSRQ request:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:DesignatePrinterRQ ReturnHostCommand="true" Version="2.0.1">
         <ns:Printers>
            <ns:Ticket CountryCode="countryTicketPrinterTypeCodeHere" LNIATA="printerLineAddressHere" />
         </ns:Printers>
      </ns:DesignatePrinterRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

You will need the values for CountryCode and LNIATA to be provided by Sabre.
You can contact Sabre using the contact us form at: https://developer.sabre.com/contact

Information on the associated Sabre command to the DesignatePrinterLLSRQ service is available at: https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/Printers/TicketPrinter/PrinterTicket.aspx?LanguageOverride=en&ItemID=38722B8FF6C949189864DF2641F867ED

(Login parameters --> Agent Sign In: your SOAP API Username / Password: your Sabre API Password / PCC: your Sabre API 'Organization')

Comment: As per request I've uploaded both a copy of my xml request and the xml response I receive (too long to post as comment).

The  request: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/StackOverflow/DesignatePrinter%20%28Request%29.xml)

The response: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54991757/StackOverflow/DesignatePrinter%20%28Response%29.xml)

As you can see I currently only pass a printer address. Perhaps that is what is causing my problems?

Comment: The absence of country code is most likely related to the problem.
You should be able to get that by contacting Sabre (provide your IPCC) as stated above, or the travel agency for which you are developing the solution.